# error instaling symfony plugin

Tags: symfony1, symfony-plugins

I tried to install the `sfFormExtraPlugin` plugin from symfony and I got the following errors:

```
C:\wamp\www\sgps>symfony plugin:install sfFormExtraPlugin
>> plugin    installing plugin "sfFormExtraPlugin"

Warning: require_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file or director
y in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\PEAR\symfony\plugin\sfPearEnvironment.class.php on
 line 15

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='.
;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\PEAR\symfony\plugin\sfPearEnvironmen
t.class.php on line 15
```

I checked and the `sfPearEnvironment.class.php` is in the fold `Plugin`. What can I do to correct this situation? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install PEAR on your server.

Check this page on the PEAR website for more information about installing and configuring PEAR on your server: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Comment: I updated it, i guess :), and sfFormExtraPlugin Install worked. thank you